# Map positioning and routing on Android

Tags: gps, routing, spatialite, android

I have been instructed to create an small offline application in Android that have to:

a) Use our own map in JPEG format as the basemap (Google Maps / OpenStreetMap is not applicable)

b) Show the GPS coordinates from external Bluetooth GPS (Google map services not applicable too!!)

c) Use Spatialite to build network for shortest path calculation

d) Display the route information on top of the JPEG

I am new to the Android application. I am confused with:

1. After converting GPS data from WGS84 to Local coordinate system to Image coordinate system (x,y pixels), any JavaScript can help to show it on top of the JPEG file by a marker?
2. Are there any map viewer available for displaying the georeferenced image file?
3. How to display the route data (Lines) from Spatialite on top of the map?

I found most of the related Android apps make use of Google Maps or OpenStreetMap, but none of them make use of the image file for positioning and navigation. I am not clearly understanding how can I combine all those of things (JPEG only, Spatialite, GPS data) together, or are there any simple ways to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can start to have a look at [Vespucci](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vespucci).

It is an opensource OSM editor for Android devices who can display map tiles mainly from OSM based sources, but it should be possible to display any other non-tiled map imagery, I assume.

And inside Vespucci you can display the current GPS position, but I am not aware whether this is using any google service or an own framework.

And Vespucci is drawing own graphic elements on the background map, namely the real graphic objects derived from raw XML OSM data.

So why not strip off all really OSM stuff from Vespucci and display your own graphic / elements?